# Определение штата оффлайн

Tags: java

Как определить штат по координатам, без запросов к google map. Желательно оффлайн

Comment: Добрый день ! Прошу ,это вам поможет [лови гитару](http://www.baeldung.com/geolocation-by-ip-with-maxmind)